# A-GPS on BlackBerry OS 5

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mobile, gps

I'm developing an application that is targeting Blackberry OS 5.0 mobile devices and I'm testing on a BlackBerry Curve 9300 on T-Mobile UK (GSM?). I'm having absolutely no luck getting location updates with the A-GPS using `GPS_MODE_ASSIST` (or even a rough fix via CELLSITE) even though the device reports it as supported via `GPSInfo.isGPSModeAvailable()`. It is possible to get a location fix using AUTONOMOUS however the time to first fix is often unusably high. I wonder if anyone could offer any suggestions for getting the A-GPS to work or how to improve the time to first fix?

```
BlackBerryCriteria myCriteria = new BlackBerryCriteria(GPSInfo.GPS_MODE_ASSIST); 
BlackBerryLocationProvider locationProvider = (BlackBerryLocationProvider)    LocationProvider.getInstance(myCriteria);
locationProvider.setLocationListener(new LocationListener() {

                public void locationUpdated(LocationProvider provider, Location location) {
                    if (location.isValid()) {
                        // display some interesting values on the screen.
                        double longitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLongitude();
                        double latitude = location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getLatitude();
                        int accuracy = (int) location.getQualifiedCoordinates().getHorizontalAccuracy();
                        GPSDemo.this.appendScreenText("\nlat, long: " + latitude + ", " + longitude + " accuracy: " + accuracy + "m");
                    }
                }

                public void providerStateChanged(LocationProvider provider, int newState) {
                    if (newState == LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE) {
                        provider.reset();
                    }
                    screen.setState(newState);
                }
            }, 1, -1, -1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assisted GPS and CellSite fixes require support from the wireless network. Prior to OS 6.0 that support has to come from your wireless carrier. On 6.0 and latter RIM provides some support.

Comment: Interesting! Do you have further info/links for this?

Comment: I had a nagging feeling that this might be the case. So do I have any options if I want to improve the time to first fix?

Comment: I would have to do a lot of digging to come up with links. The criteria I use now (on 6.0) comes up with a first fix almost instantly. Similar to Google, a large radius of error that shrinks as the GPS locks in. Without assistance the best way to get a quick first fix is to ensure you have a good view of the sky, and keep your ephemeris up to dat by using the GPS regularly.